# How to assign a value to a variable in Android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do a simple text game where the player has a weapon.

I want that, when clicking a certain option, the value that holds the weapon name "knife" gets updated to "sword".

I made a resources string that holds the "knife" value but can't seem to find a syntax that will update it.i already read that maybe you can't change resource values. Is this true?

If it is. How do I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: question is unclear, try to edit it and make it more clear please.

Comment: Question is clear to me

Comment: Question unclear for me too. Can you please at least add the related code?

Comment: Whenever you post a question on StackOverflow, and problem itself is related to code you should post that code, so we can analyse a problem. In This case please edit your question and post some sign of your work. Greetings

Comment: While I understood the issue, the others are correct. Try to include a [mcve] when asking and don't forget to accept an answer when you get the solution (as well as upvote any others who help you along the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you really need to go back and start with the basics of Android and Internationalization. **It is not possible to update a resource at runtime**, as you have correctly discovered, so it is your approach that needs to change.

Here is an example:

```
TextView text;
String value = getString(R.string.knife);
text.setText(value);
```

It seems that `onClick` you try to do something like:

```
setString(R.string.knife, "sword");
```

Which is impossible. Instead, you need to have the two strings as separate resources and then switch your value to the new resource when needed. So simply:

```
value = getString(R.string.sword);
text.setText(value); //and reset the display
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, if anyone stumbles upon the same problems, I found a good solution with [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). It allows saving variable values in the device's memory.